# Redirect user to the same page after logging out

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Sometimes I would like to be able to have a user log out, but stay on the page they were already on.

I'm using [invalidateSession](http://ember-simple-auth.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#SimpleAuth-ApplicationRouteMixin-invalidateSession) to log the user out, but this reloads the application and takes them to my application's root URL - the login page. In some cases, this is not the behavior I want, and I would instead like to have the user stay on the page they're on, but show the "logged out" version of that page.

Is there a way to log a user out and either a) not reload the application, or b) specify which page they should be redirected to after log out?

I've tried transitioning to another route, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this *after* the session is invalidated (it's not a promise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your application route you can override this by doing something like

```
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {

actions: {
  sessionInvalidationSucceeded: function(){
   var currentRoute = this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');
   this.transitionTo(currentRoute); // or whatever route you want
  },
  sessionInvalidationFailed: function(error){
    console.log(error);
    var currentRoute = this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');
    this.transitionTo(currentRoute); // or whatever route you want
  }
}
});
```

the default behavior of sessionInvalidationSucceeded is do basically a window reload and you can override this by overriding the method

Comment: Does it have to be in the application route? Could it be in the route that is specific to this page where I need the different behavior?

Comment: you could try that and see if it works or just check the currentRoute variable which should be the route of the current page your on, if it is equal to a certain route do something otherwise do something else